# Cannot convert int {Class}::* to int*

Tags: c++, casting, int

When I try to call a function, passing in a reference to my variable which has the type int, to the function which takes a type of int, I get an error that seems to point out that the int is the type of the class it was declared in, why is this?

Header:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        int MAJOR = 3;
        int MINOR = 3;
        int REV = 0;
}
```

Code:

```
glfwGetVersion(&MyClass::OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, &MyClass::OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, &MyClass::OPENGL_VERSION_REV);
```

Error:

```
error: cannot convert 'int MyClass::*' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void glfwGetVersion(int*, int*, int*)'
```

Comment: That's out parameters, just use local variables of type int

Comment: Your MAJOR/MINOR/REV are instance members, but you're referencing them using a class. You either need to create an instance of MyClass, or make the MAJOR/MINOR/REV static members.

Comment: @Thomas And what are the impacts can you please tell. Moreover did you know the reason why version members are static?

Comment: The impact is that you need to create another class if you want to get another version number.

Comment: @Thomas Which will be coupled with the data of that library and is good in my opinion. So I guess `static` is a good idea for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        static const int MAJOR = 3;
        static const int MINOR = 3;
        static const int REV = 0;
};
```

If these versions are **constant**.

---

Otherwise as:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        static int MAJOR;
        static int MINOR;
        static int REV;
};
```

Then somewhere in a `.cpp` file

```
int MyClass::MAJOR = 3;
int MyClass::MINOR = 3;
int MyClass::REV = 0;
```

Check [live example here](http://ideone.com/aHqbQb)

Comment: Can't pass const int to glfwGetVersion, needs int*

Comment: @user1763295 In that case, use the second solution.

Comment: Worked thankyou, had to declare them as int MyClass:Var though not static int MyClass::Var when I was setting them in the cpp file

Comment: @Thomas Because library version (opengl in this case) remains same throughout the program. You can have many other non-static members that are initialized per object. But version numbers that is initialized just once at program load.

Comment: While that may be true, you'll need several version classes, one for OpenGL, one for Windows, one for DirectSound, .... Why not create an object of it?

Comment: @Thomas As I said MyClass is just representative and may contain many more per instance members. Keeping version info in all instance is waste. Decoupling it into a different class may not be a good idea either. Otherwise you can do whatever you want, compiler won't complain you, it is only about code maintenance.

Comment: Just adding for late readers stumbling over here: Since C++17 it is possible to alternatively declare the variables `inline` such as `inline static int const MAJOR = 3;` (initialisation included), allowing to skip the definition in the CPP file.

Answer (score 3):

`&MyClass::OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR` is a pointer on member.

You may use

```
MyClass instance;

glfwGetVersion(&instance.OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,
               &instance.OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,
               &instance.OPENGL_VERSION_REV);
```

Comment: @DigviJayPatil More correct if OP wants to read the version for each instance of object, which most possibly he does not.